# Lagrange-Interpolation-not showing the plots, because of an error message, which I can't fix

Tags: plot, interpolation, scilab

So, I am trying to write a program , that computes the Lagrange Interpolation in a given interval [a,b]. My code works (I printed out the results on different points of the program), but I can't seem to get a good plot. This is my code:

```
funcprot(0)
clear all

clf()

    a = -5 
    b = 5 
    j = 100 
    n = [3;9;15;36] 

function fx = func(x) 

    fx = -x/(2+x^6)

endfunction

function y = Lagrange(t, f, x) 

    n_t = size(t,'r') 
    n_x = size(x,'r')
    disp(n_t)
    disp(n_x)
    y = zeros(n_x,1)

    for k = 1:n_x 

    POL = 0

    for i = 1:n_t

    L_k = 1

    for l = 1:n_t

    if (l ~= i) then 

    L_k = L_k * (x(k)-t(l))/(t(i)-t(l))

    end 

    end

    POL =  POL + f(i)*L_k

    end 

    y(k) = POL

    end

endfunction

    x = linspace(a,b,j)' 
    fx = func(x)
    m = size(n, 'r')



    for i=1:m

    xi = linspace(a,b,n(i))'
    fxi = func(xi)

    yi1 = Lagrange(xi, fxi, x) 

    subplot(2,m,i)
    plot2d(x,[yi1,fx], rect=[a,-0.4,b, 0.4], style=[2,5])
    plot2d(xi,fxi, style=[-6])
    title(strcat(['Number of grid-points =: ',string(n(i))]))

    c = zeros(n(i),1)

    for j=1:n(i) 

    c(j) = (a+b)/2+((b-a)/2)*cos(((2*j-1)*%pi)/(2*n(i)))

    end

    fc = func(c)

    yi2 = Lagrange(c,fc,x) 
    subplot(2,m,i+m)
    plot2d(x,[yi2,fx],rect=[a,-0.4,b, 0.4], style=[2,5])
    plot2d(c,fc, style=-6)
    title(strcat(['Chebyshev = ',string(n(i))]))

    end
```

I always get the following error message:

```
plot2d: Wrong size for input argument #7: 2 < 101 expected.
```

That means, that my plot function plot2d is somehow wrong, but I can't understand why. I tried changing 'rect' and 'style', but that didn't help and furthermore, they only determine the boundaries and the shape of the curve. I am starting to believe my mistake is somewhere else, but I can't seem to find. WHen I remove 'rect' and 'style', I get some graphs, but they aren't correct at all, as they are just straight lines and not the Lagrange-Interpolation. I would be very grateful, if someone can point out my mistake.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Here's some tip to have it run : try to match the parameters in the order and amount requested in the plot2D description :

```
plot2d(x,[yi1,fx], style=[2,5],,, rect=[a,-0.4,b, 0.4],)
plot2d(xi,fxi, style=[-6],,,)
...
plot2d(x,[yi2,fx], style=[2,5],,,rect=[a,-0.4,b, 0.4],)
plot2d(c,fc, style=-6,,,)
```

I can't undersand atm why you have to do this, since they are optionnal arguments, but at least, your have your result (or looks like you have stg a step further, at least!)